# PHP looping context query

Tags: php, loops

A question that has always puzzled me is why people write it like the first version when the second version is smaller and easier to read.  I thought it might be because php calculates the `strlen` each time it iterates. any ideas?

FIRST VERSION

```
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($key); $i < $len; $i++) {}
```

You can obviously use `$len` inside the loop and further on in the code, but what are the benefits over the following version?

SECOND VERSION

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i++) {}
```

Comment: Because your second version will recalculate `strlen` at every loop and slow-down the performances.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.. Put it in an answer and gain some points :)

Comment: You understand the reason. To see if it makes a big difference you can test it. Time a big loop, and you will have your answer. I think there will be very little difference, especially if a reasonable amount is done inside the loop.

Comment: you can use this to loop 1.000.000 times and then check the difference in miliseconds (in time before and after the loop). this will answer your question.

Comment: So i suppose the decision is storing a small number for `$len` is worth the time saved and readability to iterate

Comment: I prefer `while($i--)`, but I found this interesting: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: It's worth noting that $len in the first example will still be set when you leave the loop. Defining it there doesn't really do anything. You can define it on the line before the loop for cleaner looking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of performance.

Your first version of the `for` loop will recaculate the `strlen` every time and thus, the performances could be slowed down.

Even though it wouldn't be significant enough, you could be surprised how much the slow can be exponantial sometimes.

You can see [here](http://www.phpbench.com/) for some performances benchmarks with loops.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is best used if the loop is expected to have many iterations and `$key` won't change in the process.

The second one is best used if the loop is updating `$key` and you need to recalculate it, or, when recalculating it doesn't affect your performance.

Comment: Tough one which to mark as correct. I like your comment saying "if the loop is updating $key and you need to recalculate it"

Comment: Depends. Should the length of key be shorter at some point without recalculating the max, you might find yourself getting an index-out-of-range exception. I'd say it is situational, and therefor must be taken in consideration!